# Identify first & last date of Financial Year from list of random date range

Tags: vba, date-range

I need to find First & Last date of Financial Year from the list of random dates.

```
Example:

Dates:
28-Mar-2015
01-Apr-2016
05-Apr-2016
.
.
.
30-Mar-2016
31-Mar-2016
03-Apr-2017
04-Apr-2017
.
.
.
26-Mar-2018
29-Mar-2018
05-Apr-2018
07-Apr-2018
.
.
10-May-2018
.
.
Till Date

Result:
FY 16-17       -> First date = 01-Apr-2016 & Last Date = 31-Mar-2017
FY 17-18       -> First date = 03-Apr-2017 & Last Date = 29-Mar-2018
FY 18-19 (Current) -> First date = 05-Apr-2018 & Last Date = Till date (Last possible date)
```

**- *Approach #1:***
For any FY, get hard-code date of Apr-16 & Mar-17 month, but that is not effective

```
Set fystart = Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("E:E").Find(CDate("Apr-2016"), Lookat:=xlWhole)
Set fyend = Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("E:E").Find(CDate("Mar-2017"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

*But it only finds 01-Apr-2016 or 01-Mar-2017*

**- *Approach #2:***

Tried to use MIN & MAX function but it returns Min & Max of whole random date list

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when you say the first and last dates of the financial year do you actually mean the oldest and newest dates in the list? If not, what do you expect the correct results to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-VBA approach: you can use `IF` and `MIN` or `MAX` to create an array formula to do this (entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Since your FY begins on 01-Apr and ends on 31-Mar of the following year, I added two helper columns: "BEGINS" and "ENDS", with the relevant dates below.

[image: table]

The formula for "FIRST DATE" is `{=MIN(IF($E$1:$E$13>=B16,$E$1:$E$13))}`, where `$E$1:$E$13` is your list of dates, and `B16` is the "Begins" date.

Similarly, "LAST DATE" is `{=MAX(IF($E$1:$E$13<=C16,$E$1:$E$13))}`, where `C16` is the "Ends" date.

This works because `IF($E1:$E$13<=C16...` returns a "filtered" array of dates which you can then find the `MAX` or `MIN` of.